# Dynamic use of Alexa Presentation Language

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

I'm trying to use [Alexa Presentation Language](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-overview.html). I want to know how to incorporate dynamic strings (like *Output Speech* and *Title*) in node.js ([Binding](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-data-binding-evaluation.html#extending-the-data-binding-context) to be specific).

If I use some static strings for `outputSpeech` and put it in `apl_template_export.json`, then the skill functions properly and I can see output in Device Display. But when I try to use [binding](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-data-binding-evaluation.html#extending-the-data-binding-context), the skill fails. Although there is no error, but I can't see any output in Device Display either (See Image).
[image]

Here is what I've been trying so far:

```
handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .addDirective({
                  type: 'Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument',
                  version: '1.0',
                  document: require('./apl_template_export.json'),
                  dataSources: {
                    "bodyTemplate1Data": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "objectId": "bt1Sample",
                        "title": urlParams.type,
                        "textContent": {
                            "primaryText": {
                                "type": "PlainText",
                                "text": outputSpeech
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
              })
            .speak(outputSpeech)
            .getResponse();
```

**apl_template_export.json**:

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "1.0",
    "import": [
        {
            "name": "alexa-layouts",
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    ],
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "payload"
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "Text",
                "text": "${dataSources.bodyTemplate1Data.textContent.primaryText.text}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I replace `${dataSources.bodyTemplate1Data.textContent.primaryText.text}` with actual text (like *"Hello World"*), the skill works as intended.

I took reference from [here](https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-level-up-riddles/blob/c87d8b23cb5d97470d379dc5143c70bf1460c277/lambda/custom/question.json#L363) and [here](https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-level-up-riddles/blob/c87d8b23cb5d97470d379dc5143c70bf1460c277/lambda/custom/index.js#L15), original repository: https://github.com/alexa-labs/skill-sample-nodejs-level-up-riddles

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

### UPDATE

I changed the `text` variable to this:

```
"items": [
            {
                "type": "Text",
                "text": "Type: ${type}\nDatasources: ${dataSources != null} \nBodyTemplate: ${dataSources.bodyTemplate1Data != null}"
            }
        ]
```

And I'm getting this as output:

```
Type: undefined
Datasources: false 
BodyTemplate: false
```

So the problem is not in rendering the output, instead the **template is not able to load the `dataSources`**, that is the actual problem.

It is not even able to load `type` variable whose value is already defined in the template.

Comment: Can you capture cloudwatch error and post it in your question?

Comment: There is no error. I'm receiving a output (see image). But Alexa display device is not able to render it.

Comment: kindly confirm in logs... getting output doesn't mean there is no error. I was getting same error and reviewing logs helped me further (output is visible but ui is blank ) Do you have SessionEndedRequestHandler defined as well? try commenting it

Comment: I checked last 5 entries in the logs and there was no error. And I do have my `SessionEndedRequestHandler` defined. But I think it's not the problem of `SessionEndedRequestHandler` as I'm launching the Skill and terminating it yet. (`shouldEndSession` is `False` )

Comment: @AmodGokhale please see the update in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're generating a `template` from [APL Authoring Tool](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-presentation-language/apl-authoring-tool.html), then here are the points to remember:

1. While adding a `directive` to your `responseBuilder`, make sure that you add a `key` named `datasources`.
2. When referencing a `datasource` from your template, make sure that you address it as `payload`. So your `datasource` is referenced as `payload`.

For eg:

```
datasources : {
    'type': 'AlexaHeader',
    'text': {
        'value': 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

If you want to access `value` then reference it as `${payload.text.value}`.

3. If these doesn't work, then re-enable APL from your console.